# JSON Template in Lua

Tags: json, lua, jsontemplate

I have a JSON object which I would like to templatize in lua. For example:

```
{
  "type":"email",
  "version":"1.0",
  "account":"%emailId%"
}
```

I would like to substitute the %emailId% with a list of e-mail ids. Is there a templatization support for JSON in lua?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no built-in support for either JSON or templating in the core Lua language or libraries. There are a number of [JSON modules](http://lua-users.org/wiki/JsonModules) available, but I'm not sure whether any of them have template support. You might have to write a templating function yourself, but it probably won't be too hard - it's just a matter of iterating over all the string values with the JSON module and using [string.gsub](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4) on them.

Answer (score 1):

Though it isn't intended for JSON you can use [lua-resty-template](https://github.com/bungle/lua-resty-templateb).

user.json:

```
{ "user": "{{username}}" }
```

lua-code:

```
local template = require "resty.template"
local result = template.compile("user.json")({ username = "someone" })
print(result);
```

result:

```
{ "user": "someone" }
```